# Vim AutoComplPop issues?

Tags: command-line, vim

I need auto-completion in vim for programming languages, for that I downloaded the [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879)
followed the instructions mentioned there and copied the files `cp -r`

```
Downloads/ns9tks-vim-l9-3bb534a720fa/plugin/*
Downloads/ns9tks-vim-l9-3bb534a720fa/doc/*
Downloads/ns9tks-vim-l9-3bb534a720fa/autoload/*
```

to the vim directories

```
/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/
/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/
/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/
```

It gave the error about L9 : Vim-script library, downloaded from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3252)   and did the same with these files copied its file to the vim respective directories when I copied the `autoload` directory content of the L9 library there was sub directory named `l9` when it goes there in vim autoload directory it gave the permissions problem so I changed its permissions to `chmod 644`, now it doesn't give the L9 Library error but when I edit a file

```
vim hello.html
```

it gives the errors when I press `i` to insert and keep giving the errors if I type anything.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>9_feedPopup..<SNR>9_finishPopup:
line    4:
E117: Unknown function: l9#tempvariables#end

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and surely auto-complete doesn't work !
Help !

Answer (score 0):

i used this method to install this plugin and it worked perfectly :

1. download the latest version of the plugin fron here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879
2. create the folder "~/.vim" with the command "mkdir ~/.vim".
3. extract the contained of your downloaded file (the first step) (you will have a new folder called "vim-autocomplpop" when you finish the extraction)
4. copy all the contained of the folder "vim-autocomplpop" into the folder "~/.vim" with the command "cp -r /path/to/vim-autocomplpop/* ~/.vim/".
5. add the lines of this website in your ".vimrc" file http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/vim-autocompletion-avec-tab
6. open vim now and you'll see that it works like magic.

Comment: what is the location of "vimrc" file ? and the website you [link]( http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/vim-autocompletion-avec-tab) provided is in some other language I can not understand.  can you provide some link in English ?

Comment: when you're in your home folder use the «Ctrl + h» to see invisible files, you'll see that there is a file named ".vimrc", this file is used to load automatically some options in the start-up of vim (so you won't have to write them every time you open vim). for the website that i give you, just copy the lines that are in the blue area (those who starts with "autocmd").

Comment: i am having this [problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/404053/installing-and-uninstalling-vim) after that i dont have ".vimrc" file in home folder any i guess i have deleted it how can i reinstall and get vim back or can get those files back ? i tried re installing it but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

you just have to create another .vimrc file with this command "touch ~/.vimrc", then all what you have to do is to put this lines in it with a text editor, then you just have to do what i told you to do in the firs message(except for the 4th step because i already included those lines in this answer)

```
runtime! debian.vim

if has("syntax")

  syntax on

endif

set background=dark

set showcmd     " Show (partial) command in status line. 

set ignorecase      " Do case insensitive matching

set autowrite       " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make

set mouse=a     " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

set ts=4

set number

set lbr


set smartindent

set shiftwidth=4


autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete

autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS

autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags

autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS

autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags

autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP

autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete

highlight PmenuSel ctermfg=0 ctermbg=7 guibg=Grey


" Source a global configuration file if available

if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")

  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local

endif
```

Comment: Hi, you have already answered this question [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/402019/114818).. Moreover, this is not a different answer... So, you should instead edit the answer you already posted earlier and delete this answer... You would find a button called "edit" below the body of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the same chmod changes to the files inside that autoload/l9 directory?

So you are talking about two plugins by the same author:

AutoComplPop 2.14.1 http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879

L9           1.1    http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3252

Your text says you installed them both. I installed them both and they seem to work OK. Please double check they are installed properly. The error you are getting talks about not finding autoload/l9/tempvariables.vim line #46 where there's an end function.

If the permissions on the files in that autoload/l9 directory don't allow you to get to the proper function it seems like that would be the error it would give.